# using a java switch stament to determine what method to call and repeatedly calling that method

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm writing a java program where the user can select a sorting algorithm from a list and specify the size of an array to be sorted. The program then generates an array of the specified size filled with random integers and uses a switch statement with a case for each sorting algorithm to call the method for the user's chosen algorithm using the generated array as a parameter.

I want to update my code to allow the user to specify how many arrays are to be sorted with their chosen algorithm. I want to use a for loop to randomly generate and sort the arrays however this doesn't seem ideal because I would have to either:

1. Place the switch block inside the for loop and check it every loop, even though the same sorting algorithm will be used each time.
2. Place a for loop in each case within the switch block and have a lot of repeated code in the form of for loops.

Is there a better implementation for this than using switch cases and for loops?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your sample code that you have tried already.

Comment: Hey mate, I came back from over the weekend and cleaned up my example below a bit. You manage to get your program working how you want?

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface (perhaps even a functional interface) named `Sorter` that has a method

```
int [] sort( final int [] values )
```

or

```
var sort( final int [] values )
```

if you sort the array in-place.

Implement that interface for each sorting algorithm.

Then you can have a variable `Sorter sorter` in your program that holds the implementation; it will be initialised in your `switch/case` statement, based on the user selection.

In your `for` loop, you will call `sorter.sort()` for each array to sort.

You can even avoid the `switch/case` statement by creating a `Map<String,Sorter>` data structure that is initialised with the name of the sort algorithm as the key and instances of the implementation of `Sorter` as the value. If `Sorter` is a functional interface, you can just assign a reference to the respective `sort()` methods to the `Map`.

However, this is known as the *Strategy* pattern …

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try throwing together an example of how you could go about this based off of `tquadrat`'s idea of using a functional interface. I hope it helps!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Sorting {

  @FunctionalInterface
  interface SortType {
    Integer[] sort(Integer[] array);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numArrays = 5;
    int numValues = 10;

    ArrayList<Integer[]> unsortedArrays = generateArrays(numArrays, numValues);
    System.out.println("Unsorted:");
    print(unsortedArrays);

    ArrayList<Integer[]> sortedArrays = sortArrays(unsortedArrays, Sorting::bubbleSort);
    System.out.println("\nSorted:");
    print(sortedArrays);
  }

  //Put together random values
  private static ArrayList<Integer[]> generateArrays(int numArrays, int numValues) {
    ArrayList<Integer[]> unsortedArrays = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < numArrays; i++) {
      Integer[] array = new Integer[numValues];
      for (int j = 0; j < numValues; j++) {
        array[j] = rand.nextInt(100);
      }
      unsortedArrays.add(array);
    }

    return unsortedArrays;
  }

  //Loop through using the given sorting method on each array
  private static ArrayList<Integer[]> sortArrays(ArrayList<Integer[]> arrays, SortType sortType) {
    ArrayList<Integer[]> sortedArrays = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer[] array : arrays) {
      sortedArrays.add(sortType.sort(array));
    }
    return sortedArrays;
  }

  //Example sort to use with parameters and return matching the interface
  private static Integer[] bubbleSort(Integer[] array) {
    int n = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
          int temp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[j + 1];
          array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    return array;
  }

  //Method to print the results
  private static void print(ArrayList<Integer[]> arrays) {
    for (Integer[] array : arrays) {
      for (Integer i : array)
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

}
```

Sample output:

```
Unsorted:
67, 54, 83, 67, 62, 96, 6, 24, 66, 19, 
3, 37, 45, 36, 81, 45, 5, 46, 5, 84, 
10, 8, 95, 50, 82, 38, 36, 18, 80, 98, 
52, 27, 18, 17, 77, 51, 18, 72, 55, 76, 
79, 84, 92, 85, 61, 74, 64, 29, 95, 64, 

Sorted:
6, 19, 24, 54, 62, 66, 67, 67, 83, 96, 
3, 5, 5, 36, 37, 45, 45, 46, 81, 84, 
8, 10, 18, 36, 38, 50, 80, 82, 95, 98, 
17, 18, 18, 27, 51, 52, 55, 72, 76, 77, 
29, 61, 64, 64, 74, 79, 84, 85, 92, 95,
```